# Specify the spherical covariance in numpy's multivariate_normal random sampling

Tags: numpy, random

In numpy manual, it is said:

```
Instead of specifying the full covariance matrix, popular approximations include:  
    Spherical covariance (cov is a multiple of the identity matrix)
```

Has anybody ever specified spherical covariance? I am trying to make it work to avoid building the full covariance matrix, which is too much memory-consuming.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? are you trying to build a spherical covariance matrix that reasonably approximates your full covariance matrix? In this case, more information is needed about your specific problem.

Comment: It is this: there is a 512X512 array of variables, every variable is correlated to its neighbour within the radius of 256, and the correlation coefficient is some kind of inversely proportional to the distance. So I tried to treat this array as an 1-D array with size of 512x512=262144, and build the `cm`(whose size is 262144x262144) for it, then make a multivariate random sample.

Comment: A brute force approach is indeed impractical. What the part you quote says is what Robert Kern and Jaime have implemented in their response: it consists in completely forgetting about the correlations. If you can find a way to diagonalize analytically the full covariance matrix, or some approximation of it, you can generate independent random variables and then combine them to recover correlations…

Answer (score 1):

If you just have a diagonal covariance matrix, it is usually easier (and more efficient) to just scale standard normal variates yourself instead of using `multivariate_normal()`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> stdevs = np.array([3.0, 4.0, 5.0])
>>> x = np.random.standard_normal([100, 3])
>>> x.shape
(100, 3)
>>> x *= stdevs
>>> x.std(axis=0)
array([ 3.23973255,  3.40988788,  4.4843039 ])
```

Comment: Maybe it is not right to call it "spherical", since the matrix is not diagonal. Here is the whole problem:there is a 512X512 array of variables, every variable is correlated to its neighbour within the radius of 256, and the correlation coefficient is some kind of inversely proportional to the distance. So I tried to treat this array as an 1-D array with size of 512x512=262144, and build the `cm`(whose size is 262144x262144) for it, then make a multivariate random sample.

Comment: Okay yes, this is very much not spherical in the sense that the documentation was using the term. You have a spherical covariance *function* in the 2-D geometric space your grid is embedded in, but that does not make a spherical covariance *matrix* in the 262144-D sampling space. You want to sample from a Gaussian random field. You can try using the Gaussian Process functionality in [PyMC](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc), though it won't be very efficient as it doesn't really handle the special case of grids. Googling for "python gaussian random field" might give you some leads.

Answer (score 1):

While @RobertKern's approach is correct, you can let numpy handle all of that for you, as `np.random.normal` will do broadcasting on multiple means and standard deviations:

```
>>> np.random.normal(0, [1,2,3])
array([ 0.83227999,  3.40954682, -0.01883329])
```

To get more than a single random sample, you have to give it an appropriate size:

```
>>> x = np.random.normal(0, [1, 2, 3], size=(1000, 3))
>>> np.std(x, axis=0)
array([ 1.00034817,  2.07868385,  3.05475583])
```

Comment: It seems to be working indeed, but I can't find this behavior in the documentation (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html). Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: No, it's not documented, but it is reliable. The parameters will be broadcast against each other, and each broadcasted set of parameters will be sampled independently.